# Nice array from pluck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model and I love the pluck method I can use. If I do this:

```
@x = AwesomeModel.all.pluck(:column_one, :column_two)
```

then I get a multidimensional array: @x[][]. With my sad skills, I work with them using the numbers:

```
@x[0][1]
```

how can I can use pluck or a similar method to access the array something like this:

```
@x[0][:column_two]
```

Comment: What version of ruby? `.to_h` is available for turning into a hash in Ruby 2.1.

Comment: version 2.0.0 - too bad I have Rails running on multiple platforms, can't really afford to break my platforms...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are concerned about the structure of what you get back from the db, you should simply do:

```
@x = AwesomeModel.all.select(:column_one, :column_two)
```

Then you'd keep the fast db query advantage + have `AwesomeModel` instances, but with only `column_one` and `column_two` filled

---

Or if you desire to do it manually:

```
@x = AwesomeModel.all.pluck(:column_one, :column_two).map do |array|
  OpenStruct.new({column_one: array[0], column_two: array[1] }) }
end
```

Then you can use it like a regular model:

```
@x[0].column_one
# or even
@x[0][:column_two]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.pluck_hash(*args)
    plucked = pluck(*args)
    plucked.map {|ary| Hash[args.zip ary]}
  end
end

AwesomeModel.all.pluck_hash(:column_one, :column_two)
#=> [{:column_one => 'value', :column_two => 'value}, {...}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `.all.pluck`, because it returns an array of values, and that makes you loose all the advantages of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Instead use `AwsomeModel.method` directly, it would create the query but not run it until you need it, `AwsomeModel.select(:column_1, :column_2)` would create a

```
select (awesome_models.column_1, awsome_models.column_2)
```

query, and the result would be an array of `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, which are still chainable, and values are still under keys of the column name eg:

```
AwsomeModel.select(:column_1, :column_2).first.column_1
```

Instead of

```
AwesomeModel.all.pluck(:column_1, :column_2).first[0] # or .first.first
```

Comment: Is there a reference where I can find those ActiveRecord::Relation advantages? Right now I am using Rails to generate mockups. I'd love to learn more about it than the scaffolding feature.

Comment: `all` method since rails 4 returns relation, not an array.

Comment: I know, but `pluck` turns it into an array